# Execute *.exe file with PHP exec() on Windows localhost

Tags: php, exe

I use the following PHP code to execute the a local exe program resting on one of the disk, I do this for testing purposes to see how local file execution will work on localhost system (WAMP) whether it has discrepancy or not. Normally that pieces of code and whole set of files will reside on server side.

In my case PHP exec() function behaves erratically, if I call exec() with  `C:/Windows/Notepad.exe` then it fires up the notepad on background but nothing is visible, the only way that I know the notepad is executed is from task manager that another notepad.exe is spawned in process tab.

On the other hand, if I call exec() with 'F:/File.exe' there is not any sign that File.exe is executed (from task manager) nor produces the expected results. I set all of the file permissions to guarantee that I'm not hindered by any restrictions.

```
<?php 
 $file = 'F:/File.exe';
    if (file_exists($file)) echo 'File does exist  ::   ' . $file;
    exec($file . ' 2>&1', $output);
    //echo $output;
?>
```

Comment: is f: reachable from apache/php user and group?

Comment: how can check this ?

Comment: In order to avoid any diffculties with file presmissons I changed the location of file to be executed to `C:\wamp\www\File.exe"`, now it should be reachable.